# Two identical properties not matching as expected

Tags: powershell

As you can see from the example below, I am expecting the two `StartTime` properties to return true when compared to one another. When I compare the `StartTime` property it returns false, yet when I compare any other property it returns true, as demonstrated using the `Name` property. Is it a datetime quirk?

```
$MeterLog = Get-Content -Raw -Path (Join-Path $Path $File) | ConvertFrom-JSON 

$OpenApplications = get-process | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0 -and $_.Product -ne "Microsoft® Windows® Operating System"} | select-object Name, Description, Product, ProductVersion, Path, Company, StartTime


PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $OpenApplications[0] | gm


   TypeName: Selected.System.Diagnostics.Process

Name           MemberType   Definition                                                                    
----           ----------   ----------                                                                    
Equals         Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                
GetHashCode    Method       int GetHashCode()                                                             
GetType        Method       type GetType()                                                                
ToString       Method       string ToString()                                                             
Company        NoteProperty System.String Company=Google Inc.                                             
Description    NoteProperty System.String Description=Google Chrome                                       
Name           NoteProperty string Name=chrome                                                            
Path           NoteProperty System.String Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Product        NoteProperty System.String Product=Google Chrome                                           
ProductVersion NoteProperty System.String ProductVersion=71.0.3578.98                                     
StartTime      NoteProperty datetime StartTime=11/01/2019 13:17:19                                        



PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $MeterLog.data[0] | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name           MemberType   Definition                                                             
----           ----------   ----------                                                             
Equals         Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                         
GetHashCode    Method       int GetHashCode()                                                      
GetType        Method       type GetType()                                                         
ToString       Method       string ToString()                                                      
Company        NoteProperty string Company=Google Inc.                                             
Description    NoteProperty string Description=Google Chrome                                       
Name           NoteProperty string Name=chrome                                                     
Path           NoteProperty string Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Product        NoteProperty string Product=Google Chrome                                           
ProductVersion NoteProperty string ProductVersion=71.0.3578.98                                     
StartTime      NoteProperty datetime StartTime=11/01/2019 13:17:19
```

Date comparison returning false:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $MeterLog.data[0].StartTime -eq $OpenApplications[0].StartTime
False
```

Example of any other property returning true:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $MeterLog.data[0].Name -eq $OpenApplications[0].Name
True
```

---

Edit:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $MeterLog.data[0].StartTime

11 January 2019 13:17:19


PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $OpenApplications[0].StartTime

11 January 2019 13:17:19
```

Comment: How are you grabbing this information in the two variables? That being $OpenApplications and $MeterLog.

Comment: datetime objects have more detail than what the default display shows. for instance, your two props show seconds as the least part. there are also milliseconds ...

Comment: @Persistent13 Updated to show the source. `$Open...` comes directly from running `get-process`. `$Meter...` is a conversion from JSON.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I can't seem to prove that to be true - can you please advise?

Comment: @Arbiter - try the `.Ticks`, the `.TimeOfDay`, or the `.Milliseconds` properties

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yeah, they're different. I believe saving the object to JSON must set ticks/ms to 0 or round something up? `$Meter...` is `636828094391760000` (suspicious number of 0's) and `$Open..` is `636828094391769286`

Comment: @Arbiter - good to know where the glitch is. you may want to change your comparison to use only the parts you want - seconds may be sufficient for your needs. doing a `.ToString()` and then back to `[datetime]` is awkward, but it does work to quickly get your desired granularity.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey, great advice. I've opted to use `($_.StartTime).Millisecond -eq ($App.StartTime).Millisecond` in my comparison loop - thanks for your help!

Comment: @Arbiter - kool! you are most welcome ... glad to have helped a tad! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the datetime was modified by saving to JSON and then retrieving from  JSON, we can see this below. It seems that JSON drops everything after the decimal place in milliseconds:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $MeterLog.data[0].StartTime.TimeOfDay


Days              : 0
Hours             : 13
Minutes           : 17
Seconds           : 19
Milliseconds      : 176
Ticks             : 478391760000
TotalDays         : 0.553694166666667
TotalHours        : 13.28866
TotalMinutes      : 797.3196
TotalSeconds      : 47839.176
TotalMilliseconds : 47839176



PS C:\ProgramData\agent> $OpenApplications[0].StartTime.TimeOfDay


Days              : 0
Hours             : 13
Minutes           : 17
Seconds           : 19
Milliseconds      : 176
Ticks             : 478391769286
TotalDays         : 0.553694177414352
TotalHours        : 13.2886602579444
TotalMinutes      : 797.319615476667
TotalSeconds      : 47839.1769286
TotalMilliseconds : 47839176.9286
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to do which the export, you might want to consider to use [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression/2.7.0) from the PowerShell Gallery. It serializes an object to a PowerShell expressiom and is more strict with PowerShell object types.